# Server running error in parcel by starting the external file index.html I Ignoring the main but it also doesn't work(Build Failed)

Tags: javascript, html

[Build Error in parcel @ 2.7.0 start when I am trying to add external index.html file in the main I also ignored  the main but it also doesn't work for me. Will please someone help me to solve this problem It also not working with JavaScript file when I added externally and also getting error with html file  but I want to add the html file but as a solution I try to add JavaScript file but it also doesn't work for me. Will please someone solve this issue or tell me how to solve this issue

```
{
  "name": "forkify",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "unrelated.js",
  "targets": {
    "main": false
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel start index.html",
    "build": "parcel build index.html"
  },
  "author": "Meelad Sultan",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel": "^2.7.0"
  }
}

enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

At last I can find the solution of my problem after almost a day if someone else facing the same problem they just do add the **Browsers list ** in the  **package.json** file before script and ignore the **main target** and also set the parcel to **latest** then the parcel will run successfully and do not give any server  error or build error. And don't forget to run periodically **npx browerlist@latest --update-db.** It will update your package-lock file with new **caniuse-lite** version. In this case, you will be sure that last **two version** or **> 0.2%** will target what you expect
{
"name": "forkify",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "unrelated.js",
"target": {
"main": false
},
"browserslist": "> 0.5%, last 2 versions, not dead",
"scripts": {
"start": "parcel  index.html "
},
"author": "Meelad Sultan",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {
"@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.7.0",
"parcel": "latest"
},
"dependencies": {
"sass": "^1.55.0"
}
}